# How to remove the duplicate values for specific column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to remove the duplicate values which is in date_engaged column or is there any other way to get the row count without changing the values of the colums

```
DT::datatable(expand_collapse(x), rownames = F,escape = FALSE,selection=list(mode="single",target="row"),options = list(pageLength = 50,scrollX = TRUE,dom = 'tp',ordering=F,columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE),list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))),class='hover cell-border stripe')
```

Comment: Have you tried `unique(df)`?

Comment: expand_collapse(unique(x)) tried this still getting the same current output

Answer (score 0):

We could use `distinct`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  distinct(date_engaged, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

output:

```
  Incubatee partnership_type plan_end_date date_engaged
1   Janitri             <NA>          <NA>         <NA>
2      <NA>              GTM    2021-06-30   2021-06-20
3      <NA>              GTM    2021-06-30   2021-07-06
4     Total             <NA>             2            2
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Incubatee = c("Janitri", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", 
"<NA>", "Total"), partnership_type = c("<NA>", "GTM", "GTM", 
"GTM", "GRM", "<NA>"), plan_end_date = c("<NA>", "2021-06-30", 
"2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2"), date_engaged = c("<NA>", 
"2021-06-20", "2021-07-06", "2021-06-20", "2021-07-06", "2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Can you please edit this in my function or where should i use the distinct in my data frame@tarjae